# Why Stories in Agile have fibonacci series as estimates?

Tags: fibonacci, agile-project-management

All the estimates of sprint stories have estimates in fibonacci order. e. g stories with 1,2,3,5,8,13 story points. Whats the reason?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as it's not a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on [SoftwareEngineering.se] instead.

Answer (score 1):

One of the characteristics of the Fibonacci series is that the *gaps* between the values increases with their size.

When we use the Fibonacci series in estimating these gaps represent increasing uncertainty as user stories get larger.

For example, it is more difficult to estimate accurately a 13 point story than it is to estimate a 2 point story.

Comment: The increment can be as multiple of 5 also or maybe some other number. Why use fibonacci number?

Comment: Say I used multiples of 5: 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40. The gap between the first two values is 5. The gap between the last two values is also 5. Now say I use the Fibonacci series: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34. The gap between the first two values is 1. The gap between the last two values is 13.

Answer (score -1):

first of all, not *always* it happens, some team choose plain numbers for story points or sizes like XS, S, M, L, XL.
The fibonacci series is chosen usually if you want to promote discussion about the meaning of the story. It creates on purpose a gap between the sizes so that if two developers select different sizes they need to discuss about why so much difference between the two estimations.
Also, it promote to break down the story in smaller one for the big stories.
Not exact science, of course, but a way to promote a common understanding of the stories.

Hope it helps.